# How do you center an e.g. 960px wide website layout?

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar, margin

...without using margin:0 auto;

Why? It causes pages with a scrollbar to have a different center position than those pages without scrollbar, so when navigating through pages, divs are jumping. What would you suggest, guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the "jumping" effect is unavoidable because the scrollbars affect the viewport width, which in turn affects the centreline of the page. This happens regardless of technique (`text-align: center;`, `position: -50%;`, etc).

The workaround is to force the vertical scrollbar to always appear. Use this:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

[From here](http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/), but you can disregard most of the samples on that page and jump to the bottom.

Note that `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` were originally Microsoft extensions on the CSS2.x standard `overflow` property. However both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are in CSS3.

Comment: Ok then. So, when people are designing their websites, in order to have websites centered, do they use margin:0 auto;, and cope with this issue by having long pages? It looks like a very simple question and very basic, but it drives me crazy that I can't manage to use this margin property properly.

Comment: I use a variety of techniques to centre my pages, not just `margin: 0 auto;` exclusively, but they are all affected by the presence of the scrollbar but it doesn't bother me or my users. If it does, then just force the vertical scrollbar. I think you're being a tad strict with your design - remember you have no total control over the client.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to give `overflow-y: scroll;` to the HTML tag on all your pages, so they'll show up with a scroll bar on the right (inactive for the pages that don't need it). This way you'll have the same client width for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS? Only to force the scrollbar to always appear, as other answers have said.

Another route would via JavaScript - detect on DOM ready whether the page has a scrollbar, and nudge the container accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.width960container{
    width:960px;
    min-height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -480px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 960px container is still moving.